# How to access data from tableau using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, tableau-api

I wonder if I could access the data from this table:

https://public.tableau.com/profile/hans.kristian.o.lorenzana?fbclid=IwAR1NyNmuyihay_-T7qajexzmTHdG2uG38qOsmaqKIu1qRM2UECKItr1os7w#!/vizhome/BianCityCovid19Dashboard_15873861726130/Dashboard1?publish=yes

and automatically load it on my website using Javascript. How can I retrieve it without going to this website and manually change the data?

Assume that all I need is the data in the table in the far right (the one with "Barangay" "Suspect" "Probable" "Confirmed" "Recovered" and "Deceased").

Here's my javascript:

```
var langkiwaCases = {
    postiveCase: 0,
    suspect: 0,
    probable: 0,
    recovered: 0,
    deceased: 0
};

  .
  . //name of every variable is the "barangay"
  .
```

How can I access it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: no, the server dispatches an image and the front-end implements it, everything that you see is an image... have a look at your network requests and you'll see that image. Seems that backend does't want anyone to parse the data...